# find the supremum and infimum of $E =\{x \in \mathbb{R} : -1/n \le x \le 1-1/n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

[![I am not sure how to start and what it the answer of this question
please justify this answer of this question.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDgMN.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDgMN.jpg)

I am not sure how to start and what it the answer of this question
please justify this answer of this question.

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly: if $x \in E$, does the inequality hold for all $n$? Does there exist such an $n$ depending on $x$? Or is there a single $n$ for every $x$? I assume it is not the latter, because otherwise $E$ would depend on $n$, which doesn't really make sense. But I can't tell whether it is meant to be the first or second one.

Comment: Where is that question taken from? It seems rather unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is homework, I'll get you started.

The set is $E = \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left[-\frac {1}{n}, 1 - \frac {1}{n}\right]$. Try finding $E_k = \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^k \left[-\frac {1}{n}, 1 - \frac {1}{n}\right]$ for $k=1, 2, 3$, and then generalize the result to arbitrary values of $k$. Take the limit to get $E$.

You should find out that $E$ is an interval, which makes finding $\sup E$ and $\inf E$ easy.